# Laravel 5.X - Too many redirects error when using IP address

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-5.3

I am trying to redirect to /hc/ directory which holds index.php, etc. The browser is showing ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error. Please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

This was working just fine when I was using a domain name in my old hosting. Now when I am using IP it is failing.

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /hc/

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny From All
</Files>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^45.117.122.107$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://45.117.122.107/$1 [L,R=301] 

# Protect application and system files from being viewed 
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL 
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Roll back my changes, if you don't like them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^45.117.122.107$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://45.117.122.107/$1 [L,R=301]
```

is that it redirects `^(.*)$` to itself `$1`. The client then requests the same URL again, and is redirected to itself, and requests the same again, and so on ... Using a domain name doesn't change this.

To avoid this redirect loop, or any other loop, you need some condition, which exits early or skips this rule.

---

To redirect everything to `/hc`, you can use this rule

```
RewriteRule !^hc/ /hc%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

This rule first checks, if the request isn't already for `hc`, and if it is not redirects it.

And then to rewrite each request for `/hc/` to `index.php`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php?/%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: It depends on what the rule is supposed to do. As it stands, this rule does effectively nothing, and you can just remove it.

Comment: Thanks, I have a laravel '/hc' directory in the public_html folder and my need is to redirect every request to the 'hc' directory which in turn will call the respective controller. It seems not working for me. I have commented out the lines pointed out but it still not working for me.